# How to Change Environment variable in the create process function in windows using C?

Tags: c, windows

I wrote this code to launch processes by user choice. I want to change the environment variable for the cmd shell so in the window it shows "speak to me>" instead of "C:\path>" but also can access cmd commands. I know I have to set some value instead of NULL using getenv() or putenv() function. I wrote lib function for that but I don't know how to implement this in place of Null in the create process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

// function prototype
void printError(char* functionName);

void lib(char* myFunction);
void lib(char* myFunction)
{
    char *lib;

   lib = getenv( "LIB" );
   if( lib != NULL )
      printf( "Original LIB variable is: %s\n", lib );
   _putenv( "LIB=speak to me>" );
   lib = getenv( "LIB" );
   if( lib != NULL )
      printf( " %s\n", lib );
}

int main()
{
   int i, choice;

   #define NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES 2
   LPTSTR lpCommandLine[NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES];
   PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo[NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES];

   STARTUPINFO startInfo;
   ZeroMemory(&startInfo, sizeof(startInfo));
   startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
   startInfo.lpTitle = "What is your Command?";
   startInfo.dwFillAttribute = FOREGROUND_BLUE| BACKGROUND_RED| BACKGROUND_GREEN| BACKGROUND_BLUE| BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
   startInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE;

   /* set up the command lines */
   lpCommandLine[0] = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
   lpCommandLine[1] = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";


   /* create the processes with user choice */   
  while(1)
  {
      printf("\n Please choose from the following list\n");
      printf("  0.Quit\n");
      printf("  1.Run Notepad\n");
      printf("  2.Run Cmd shell\n");
      printf(" enter number:");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
      switch(choice)
      {

      case 1:
        if( !CreateProcess(NULL, lpCommandLine[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                         HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                         NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo[0]) )
      {
          printError("CreateProcess");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Started program %d with pid = %d\n\n",1 , (int)processInfo[0].dwProcessId);
      }
      break;
      case 2:
        if( !CreateProcess(NULL, lpCommandLine[1], NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                         HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                         NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo[1]) )
      {
          printError("CreateProcess");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Started program %d with pid = %d\n\n",2 , (int)processInfo[1].dwProcessId);
      }
      break;
      case 0:
        exit(0);
      break;
      default: printf("wrong choice");
               break;
      }
  }

   /* close all the handles */
   for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++)
   {
      CloseHandle(processInfo[i].hThread);
      CloseHandle(processInfo[i].hProcess);
   }

   return 0;
}



/****************************************************************
   The following function can be used to print out "meaningfull"
   error messages. If you call a Win32 function and it returns
   with an error condition, then call this function right away and
   pass it a string containing the name of the Win32 function that
   failed. This function will print out a reasonable text message
   explaining the error and then (if chosen) terminate the program.
*/
void printError(char* functionName)
{
   LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    int error_no;
    error_no = GetLastError();
    FormatMessage(
         FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
         NULL,
         error_no,
         MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
         (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
         0,
         NULL
    );
    // Display the string.
    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s failed on error %d: ", functionName, error_no);
    fprintf(stderr, (const char*)lpMsgBuf);
    // Free the buffer.
    LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
    //ExitProcess(1);  // terminate the program
}//printError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PROMPT` environment variable can be set to something other than the default `$p$g` if you like; here is its usage:

```
PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)
```

To pass this variable in a call to `CreateProcess` you can use the `lpEnvironment` parameter:

```
    CreateProcess(NULL, lpCommandLine[1], NULL, NULL, TRUE,
            HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            (LPVOID) _T("PROMPT=speak to me$g\0\0"), NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was using  "Prompt"  after the cmd.exe that's why It was not giving me the desired result.

Comment: How can I make the menu wait until it exit from the cmd shell. Like I enter 3, it launches the process and says waiting for the program to terminate before I make another choice

Comment: launcher program should wait for the launched cmd.exe process to terminate. In other words, the launcher blocks after it launches the cmd.exe process and the launcher waits (i.e., remains blocked) until the cmd.exe process terminates. When cmd.exe terminates, your program should look up the cmd.exe exit value and output a message that states the exit value. Then the launcher should prompt the user for another choice.

Comment: I think after changing to **"speak to me>"** I can't use the _cmd commands_ in that particular prompt. But I need to use those commands like help and others

Comment: @RonitSharma You need to replicate the `path` variable as well

Comment: You need to modify/extend the parent's environment. For example, some programs will immediately crash if say "SystemRoot" isn't defined. One approach is to set/modify the variable(s), create the child with an inherited environment (i.e. `NULL`), and then restore the original environment state in the parent. This approach isn't inherently thread safe. Alternatively, copy the current environment from `GetEnvironmentStrings` and modify/extend it for use as the child's environment. This is more complicated, but inherently thread safe.

Comment: @eryksun thank you for letting me know that method but I solved that issue

Comment: @GovindParmar Thanks...  I solved that without **path** variable